# Rspec testing configuration based on environmental variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, configuration, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm conditionally using Amazon-s3 as storage for Paperclip if certain environment variables are defined. I want to test this with Rspec.

```
Application.rb

unless ENV['aws_secret_access_key'].nil? && ENV['aws_access_key_id'].nil? && ENV['aws_bucket'].nil?
   config.paperclip_defaults = {
       storage: :s3,
        s3_credentials: {
            bucket: ENV['aws_bucket'],
            access_key_id: ENV['aws_access_key_id'],
            secret_access_key: ENV['aws_secret_access_key']
        }
    }
end
```

I've tried a couple of things with no luck. Any insight as to how to go about testing this would be great. Thanks.

EDIT:

To expand on what I've attempted so far, I tried to fake the ENV variables and reload the application. This didn't work since once the application is loaded, I couldn't figure out a way to change the ENV variables.

What I'm hoping to do is test that if the application is given the above ENV variables (i.e some users may have them, some may not) that paperclip is configured to S3.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to check if the file makes it to S3 or just that the `ENV` variables are present and set? If you want to check the `ENV` variables you can simply check those against `nil`.  If you want to check `S3` you should be able to put a dummy file in `S3` and check the returned data.

Comment: What I want to do is test that the app configures paperclip to use S3 if the ENV variables are defined.

The approach I took was to fake the ENV variables, then try to initialize the application, and check that the paperclip config was S3. 

The problem I ran into was once the app is initialized, you can't re-run that snippet of code.

Comment: If some users have them and some don't, wouldn't you want to fail the test so they get the credential?  Seems like something should be looked at from a higher level.

Comment: Not necessarily. The idea is that some users will have the credentials, and that when they do, paperclip's config is set to s3 (this is what I'd like to test, that the presence of credentials changes paperclip's config to s3). For the user's that don't have credentials, the default config for paperclip would remain and the files would store locally.

Comment: Did you try anything from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#testing? You could also check something like https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L421 to see if the module is the File or S3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to test that the credentials are set correctly. You can check it, for example, as follows:

```
    Rails.application.config.paperclip_defaults[:storage][:s3_credentials][:bucket].should eql BUCKET_NAME
```

Just an extra point - I'd suggest moving the individual configurations of the S3 credentials to the environment files (`test.rb`, `development.rb`, etc.). This way, you can isolate the credentials for the individual environments. Also, you can test things more easily since you can use dummy values for credentials in test environments.

Comment: Hey Jerry. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this isn't quite what I was looking for. I expanded more above. Any new insight you might have would be great. Thanks.